# Simplest way of plotting a 3d graph in Maple?

Tags: maple

Say I have a velocity field given by **u** = (y^3, 0, 0). What is the simplest way of plotting the vorticity of this field **w** = (3y^2, 0, 0) in Maple over the domain **x** in [-3, 3], y in [-3, 3]?

Comment: More of a Maple use question than programming.  Might do better on MaplePrimes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [plots:-fieldplot3d](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/fieldplot3d) command for a 3D plot (or the [plots:-fieldplot](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/fieldplot) command for a 2D plot).

There are several options which affect the look and feel, sizing and number of the arrows, etc.

For example,

```
plots:-fieldplot3d([0,0,-3*y^2], x=-3..3, y=-3..3, z=-10..10,
                   grid=[4,8,2], arrows=`3-D`,
                   fieldstrength=log[1.2], orientation=[43,66,0]);
```

[image]

You can use the `plots:-display` command to combine several such plots, where each has its own `color` say.